# what is the solution for blue screen error (BSOD)?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, bsod

on my desktop, I have BSODs frequently on Windows Vista and 7,  with new error code every time
I need to know what cause it and how to solve this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without more information, it is hard to help you.

The first thing I would do is run a full [Memory Test](http://www.memtest.org).

If it finds anything, you need to look at replacing the faulty memory modules, if it does not - start by updating all your drivers.

If that fixes things, count yourself lucky! If it doesn't, start removing all hardware then plugging them back in one by one until you recreate the problem - then you should know what caused it.

Also - you may like a program called [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html), using this, you can see all previous blue screens your computer has had. If it is down to one driver (with different codes) it can help you speed up detection of what the problem is. If however it really is different every time, it may identify a memory problem.

Hope this helps