# Windows 7 crashes with a blue screen

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the solution for blue screen error (BSOD) ?](https://superuser.com/questions/117426/what-is-the-solution-for-blue-screen-error-bsod)

I am running win 7 32 bit on a Gateway Media Center. Without any interaction from me, and the only thing on the screen is my screen saver it crashes and the fault is "Stop" and a long string of numbers. 
I have had a "adapi sys message but now it seems to be this "Stop' MESSAGE.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

View [this](https://superuser.com/questions/117426/what-is-the-solution-for-blue-screen-error-bsod).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out a duplicate version, but I would prefer that post this as a suggestion rather than answering it with a duplicate reference